# Html.EditorFor additionalViewData

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a custom editor template where I add values to the `ViewData` like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.PhoneNumber , new { Title = "SomeValue" } )
```

How can I access both the value and the property name?

Comment: See my example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9400359/1173800

Comment: In case someone else has the same problem as me and appears here from Google - I could not understand why my ViewData["Something"] was null in my custom EditorFor. It turned out that I was loading a different view in my browser from the one where I added the anonymous type to test it out. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

ViewData is a dictionary.

You can write `ViewData["Title"]`, or you can loop through `ViewData` (which is a collection of KeyValuePairs) or `ViewData.Keys`.

Comment: Can the data also be accessible from ViewBag?

Answer (score 34):

You can nest your htmlAttributes object in view data:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { Title = "SomeValue" } })
```

Then in your editor template:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("", Model.Value, ViewData["htmlAttributes"])%>
```